# Magento 2 - Add customer e-mail to packingslip

Tags: magento2, customer-address, packing-slip

Is there a way to add the e-mail address of the customer to the packingslip in Magento 2?

Adding the following to the Address template doesn't work:

```
{{depend email}}E-mail: {{var email}}{{/depend}}|
```

Comment: Which template you have used for send mail?

Comment: I'm using the PDF for the packing slip, so the default packing slip PDF template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, I made a rewrite on "Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Renderer\DefaultRenderer", so in your di.xml from your module add the following:

```
<!--
    Rewrite to use the customer email in address templates
-->
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Renderer\DefaultRenderer"
            type="Example\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Renderer\DefaultRenderer"/>
```

Then create the file Rewrite/Magento/Customer/Block/Address/Renderer/DefaultRenderer.php in your module and add the following code:

```
<?php

namespace Example\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Renderer;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\ElementFactory;

/**
 * Class DefaultRenderer
 * @package Example\Module\Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Renderer
 */
class DefaultRenderer extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Renderer\DefaultRenderer
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface
     */
    protected $_customerMetadataService;

    /**
     * DefaultRenderer constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context
     * @param ElementFactory $elementFactory
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface $metadataService
     * @param Mapper $addressMapper
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface $customerMetadataService
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
    ElementFactory $elementFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface $metadataService,
    Mapper $addressMapper,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface $customerMetadataService,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $elementFactory, $countryFactory, $metadataService, $addressMapper, $data);
        $this->_customerMetadataService = $customerMetadataService;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     */
    public function renderArray($addressAttributes, $format = null)
    {
        switch ($this->getType()->getCode()) {
            case 'html':
                $dataFormat = ElementFactory::OUTPUT_FORMAT_HTML;
                break;
            case 'pdf':
                $dataFormat = ElementFactory::OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF;
                break;
            case 'oneline':
                $dataFormat = ElementFactory::OUTPUT_FORMAT_ONELINE;
                break;
            default:
                $dataFormat = ElementFactory::OUTPUT_FORMAT_TEXT;
                break;
        }

        $attributesMetadata = $this->_addressMetadataService->getAllAttributesMetadata();
        $attributesMetadata[] = $this->_customerMetadataService->getAttributeMetadata('email');
        $data = [];
        foreach ($attributesMetadata as $attributeMetadata) {
            if (!$attributeMetadata->isVisible()) {
                continue;
            }
            $attributeCode = $attributeMetadata->getAttributeCode();
            if ($attributeCode == 'country_id' && isset($addressAttributes['country_id'])) {
                $data['country'] = $this->_countryFactory->create()->loadByCode(
                    $addressAttributes['country_id']
                )->getName();
            } elseif ($attributeCode == 'region' && isset($addressAttributes['region'])) {
                $data['region'] = __($addressAttributes['region']);
            } elseif (isset($addressAttributes[$attributeCode])) {
                $value = $addressAttributes[$attributeCode];
                $dataModel = $this->_elementFactory->create($attributeMetadata, $value, 'customer_address');
                $value = $dataModel->outputValue($dataFormat);
                if ($attributeMetadata->getFrontendInput() == 'multiline') {
                    $values = $dataModel->outputValue(ElementFactory::OUTPUT_FORMAT_ARRAY);
                    // explode lines
                    foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
                        $key = sprintf('%s%d', $attributeCode, $k + 1);
                        $data[$key] = $v;
                    }
                }
                $data[$attributeCode] = $value;
            }
        }
        if ($this->getType()->getEscapeHtml()) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $data[$key] = $this->escapeHtml($value);
            }
        }
        $format = $format !== null ? $format : $this->getFormatArray($addressAttributes);
        return $this->filterManager->template($format, ['variables' => $data]);
    }
}
```